# Getting started with stage3d in Flash CS5, and which framework to choose?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, molehill, stage3d, flash-player-11

I have been off the stage 3d bandwagon and flash programming altogether this year, but I want to catch up on things and I need some tips.

Here's what I know: FP11 features the low level GPU stage3d API, codenamed Molehill. There are a few frameworks out there which help you access all the stage3d features more easily. (I know of Flare3D and Alternativa3D).

Which framework is best to start out with? (not just out of the mentioned 2) The rather few tutorials from Flare3D and Alternativa3D say that you require the Flex SKD / Flash Builder, but I have to use Flash CS5. -Can I?

This brings me to my next question. Can you please point me out to a place where I can see some examples/tutorials? Since FP11 was just released this fall, it seems hard to find too much help.

I'd like to try to make a rather simple 2d canvas, like the GPU accelerated option for the Photoshop canvas (which can be rotated and panned smoothly).
Having a nice cross platform gpu accelerated gallery/canvas of bitmaps and content is something I've always wanted in Flash but couldn't do with the CPU.

Cheers!

### [EDIT]

If you're having trouble manually making a FP11 profile for your Flash Pro CS5 or CS5.5, [read this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html) and install the corresponding MXP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2D / 3D frameworks**

Starling Framework leverages FP11 for 2D GPU accelerated content:

http://www.starling-framework.org/

For 3D, Away3D 4 "Broomstick" is a good option:

http://away3d.com/

**To install Flash Player 11 in Flash Professional CS5.5**

For PC, navigate the file system to Flash Pro's common configuration.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0

In that (ActionScript 3.0) directory, create a folder named "FP11" and download playerglobal.swc from Adobe - http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Assure the downloaded SWC is renamed to "playerglobal.swc"

Create a player profile so you may target Flash Player 11 in Flash Pro by navigating the file system to Flash Pro's common players at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\Players

Duplicate a pre-existing XML, such as FlashPlayer10_2.xml as a template and name it FlashPlayer11.xml

Alter:

```
<player asversion="3" id="FlashPlayer11" version="13"></player>
```

and

```
<playerdefinitionpath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP11/playerglobal.swc"></playerdefinitionpath>
```

In Flash Pro, chose Flash Player 11 for your publish settings, and set hardware settings to "Level 1 - Direct" to turn on hardware acceleration.

HTML wrapper params need the parameter:

```
params.wmode = "direct";
```

Comment: Thank you Jason for all the information! I did everything you said but I can't find "Flash Player 11" in my publish settings dropdown, the latest one is 10. (I do have FP11 installed on my system) The thing is, I don't have Flash Pro CS5.5, I have Flash Pro CS5, could that be it? Also, I didn't have a `FlashPlayer10_2.xml`, I copy pasta'd `FlashPlayer10_1.xml`, but I'm pretty sure it's the same deal.

Comment: Okay so I solved the problem using this: http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html